# How to search/filter list by multiple items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for an example or maybe a little hint for a method to filter/search list of items by multiple items typed into textbox.

Let's assume that I have a list :

```
<ul>
   <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Tea</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
   <li>Water</li>
   <li>Juice</li>
</ul>
```

What I want is to type (in textbox) for instance : Milk;Water;Juice
(with semicolon between), which returns three items.

```
$('li').filter(function() {
     ????
})
```

It could be a filter or another jquery/js function.

thank you in advance for any help

EDIT :

I forget to tell that it should search by a part of last item. For instance Coffe;Te --> return Coffe and Tea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way you can achieve this:-

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
   var search = this.value.split(';');
   $('ul li').each(function(index, element){
      $(element).toggle(search.indexOf($(element).text()) >= 0);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
<ul>
   <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Tea</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
   <li>Water</li>
   <li>Juice</li>
</ul>
```

Split the search input on `;` and check the text of each li to see if it is in the array.

**Update**

Ignore case and part match

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var search = this.value.split(';');
  $('div label').each(function(index, element) {
    var text = $(element).text().toLowerCase();
    var show = search.filter(function(e) {
      return e != '' && text.indexOf(e.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }).length > 0;
    $(element).toggle(show);
  });
});
```

```css
div label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
<div>
    <label>
      <input class="appFilterCheckbox" id="appFilterCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Coffee" />Coffee</label>
    <br/>
    <label>
      <input class="appFilterCheckbox" id="appFilterCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Tea" />Tea</label>
    <br/>
    <label>
      <input class="appFilterCheckbox" id="appFilterCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Milk" />Milk</label>
    <br/>
    <label>
      <input class="appFilterCheckbox" id="appFilterCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Water" />Water</label>
    <br/>
    <label>
      <input class="appFilterCheckbox" id="appFilterCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Juice" />Juice</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Run the snippet. It is case sensitive but that wasn't specified as a requirement.

Comment: Case sensitive isn't problem. Can I change ul and li to list of <label><input class="appFilterCheckbox" id="appFilterCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="some_text">some_text</label></br>? Sorry for requirements mixing, but they change now.

Comment: Allmost perfect :) but my inputs aren't at ul and li markup. This is my structure <div> <label><input></input></label><br> <label><input></input></label> ..... </div>

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
  var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

  $('li').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text().toLowerCase();
    if ( val.indexOf(text) > -1 ) {
      $this.show();
    } else {
      $this.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/foqagadewo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm looking for, but your example lokks good. I'll try to modify it to achive what I need. I forget to tell that it should search by a parto of last item. For instance Coffe;Te --> return Coffe and Tea

Answer (score 0):

You may have to modify Jquery autocomplete to do this for you https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

You could also create a HTML select element with 'multiple' attribute and push the    input  strings    into an array and then select the items in the select > option elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use , this will return li's that are matched.

```
var items= textboxValue.split(";")
var a= $('ul li').filter(function() {
   return items.indexOf($(this).text()) > -1 ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Documentation](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

```js
//bind chosen
$(".chosen-select").chosen({no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"});


$('.chosen-select').on('change', function(evt, params) {
    alert($(".chosen-select").val());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css">
 
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<select id="searchBox" data-placeholder="Type &apos;C&apos; to view" style="width:350px;" multiple class="chosen-select chosen-select-no-results" tabindex="11">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option>Coffee</option>
            <option>Tea</option>
            <option>Milk</option>
            <option>Water</option>
            <option>Juice</option>
          </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should Try This. please run my snippet and Enter that you want to display.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
});

function filterItems(thisobj) {
  $("ul li").hide();
  $("ul li").filter(function(i) {
    return ($(thisobj).val().split(';').indexOf($(this).text())> -1);
  }).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" onchange="filterItems(this);" />
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Water</li>
  <li>Juice</li>
</ul>
```