# How can I make selected item show in text input?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

[image]

I need to make something like that, but I don't have the knowledge. How can I go about it or the name for it?

Can anyone help me do that using jQuery, PHP or JavaScript? Thank you.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431502/how-to-search-filter-list-by-multiple-items?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check [Documentation](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

```js
//bind chosen
$(".chosen-select").chosen({no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"});


$('.chosen-select').on('change', function(evt, params) {
    alert($(".chosen-select").val());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css">
 
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<select id="searchBox" data-placeholder="Type &apos;C&apos; to view" style="width:350px;" multiple class="chosen-select chosen-select-no-results" tabindex="11">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option>Coffee</option>
            <option>Tea</option>
            <option>Milk</option>
            <option>Water</option>
            <option>Juice</option>
          </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jquery tagit plugin for the functionality

```
http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/
```